# kernel module for htc flyer

Tags: android, module, kernel, tablet, htc-android

I have to compile a kernel module for htc flyer,I got the kernel source for htc flyer from http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads 
I have compiled the same module for htc hero in the past(by pulling out the /proc/config.gz file from the device). I didn't have a htc flyer with me . can someone tell me how to compile a kernel module for htc flyer, if the process is similar to htc hero can someone please post the config.gz file for htc flyer. If not can some one tell me how to build a kernel module for htc flyer or point to resources. I googled and can not find anything useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The config files are available with the kernel source code in the folder /arch/arm/config . In this case it's flyer_defconfig